# How to draw CheckBox in rotated layout?

Tags: android, layout, rotation, draw

I have rotated a RelativeLayout with Canvas.rotate().

```
public class MyLayout
extends RelativeLayout
{
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(
            ANGLE,
            getWidth()/2,
            getHeight()/2);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

If I place a Checkbox in this layout, it is not drawn correctly after being checked, because CheckBox's draw() is not called from layout's dispatchDraw().

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I am sorry for unformated code, i am posting this from Android device.

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not drawn ***correctly*** after being checked"

Comment: It is drawn as unchecked. It looks like layout draws CheckBox's original State/Drawable. If I rotate layout just a little (rotated Checkbox lies over original Checkbox), any recent appears. It is possibly necessary to make Layout to draw all it's content in each it's dispatchDraw(). But I was not able to figure out how to make this.

Comment: That recent looks like checked drawable is drawn only in a place where rotated shape covers original shape.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Angle to rotate"/>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/angle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Rotation"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />

    <your.package.name.MyLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckMe"/>

    </your.package.name.MyLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MyLayout myLayout;
    private EditText edAngle;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myLayout = (MyLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        edAngle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.angle);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        float angleToRotate = Float.parseFloat(edAngle.getText().toString());
        myLayout.setRotationAngle(angleToRotate);
    }
}
```

MyLayout.java

```
public class MyLayout
extends RelativeLayout
{
    public float myAngle = 0;
    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }    

    public MyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(
            myAngle,
            getWidth()/2,
            getHeight()/2);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    public void setRotationAngle(float angle){

        this.myAngle = angle;
        this.invalidate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Invalidation works, but i need to handle this in layout object.

Comment: If **layout object** is the activity that holds `MyLayout` then do `MyLayout.Invalidate();`

Comment: I need to handle it in MyLayout object.

Comment: I don't understand, please be more specific(example)

Comment: Code handling this drawing (invalidation or anything else) must be in MyLayout class and called from it too. This can not be descibed by example.

Comment: If you will call it from outside, you will have to hande it manually each time, you will use this class and for many possible actions so it is bad solution.

Comment: I used ´setRotationAngle` as an example. If you don't want to call or use `setRotationAngle` place `invalidate()` in `dispatchDraw` after `canvas.restore()`

Comment: Ivalidate() wll draw layout again so placing it in dispatchDraw() will run a loop.

Comment: The best way will be to change some flags, but flags can be accessed just from android package.

Comment: I don't like leaving things unresolved. So, to make sure I understood your problem, can you post some code that reproduces this behavior? (you can't post images)

Comment: It is just necessary to draw MyLayout as invvalidated in it's each dispatchDraw().

Comment: I ask you to post some code because I made several tests and can't see any strange behavior, even without `Invalidate()`

Answer (score 0):

Working solution :

```
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
private drawn = false;
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw (Canvas canvas )
{
    canvas .save();
    canvas .rotate(
        ANGLE,
        getWidth ()/ 2,
        getHeight ()/ 2
    );
    super.dispatchDraw (canvas); 
    canvas .restore();

    if(!drawn){
        drawn = true;
        invalidate();
        drawn = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: But this solution draws layout twice. Draw it once will be better .